# Is there a better way to validate query string arguments on tornado?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

Currently, I validate a query argument like so:

```
        unmount_channel_arg = self.request.arguments.get("unmount_channel", "false")[0].decode("utf-8").lower()
        if unmount_channel_arg not in ["true", "false"]:
            # Handle it.
            ...
```

Is there a built-in tool in tornado that allows me to just provide a condition or a lambda function and act on that instead of duplicating this code each time I need to verify query arguments?

Comment: Can't you move the common logic to a base class?

Comment: I can and I probably will. I’m just trying to figure out if there’s any functionality implemented in Tornado. I might be wrong but I preferred to ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing provided by Tornado that would help you with the validation of request inputs.

My solution is to provide helper methods for different types of arguments (eg. `get_boolean_argument`) that take a default value and the source of the argument (body, query string, either).